# Bash sum numbers sequence

Tags: bash

I'm trying to SUM a sequence.

Asking for a first number and a second bigger number, the result would be like this:

> 1st number: 2
>
> 2nd bigger number: 6
>
> 2+3+4+5+6=20

I'm the whole evening stack, I have to use `for` and `seq`

```
#!/bin/sh

echo -n "Enter number 1: " 
read A
echo -n "Enter a number greater o equal than $A: "
read B
J=0

if [ $B -ge $A ]
    then     
        for i in `seq $A $B`
        do
            RES=$i=$i+$J 
            #I don't know what to do
        done
        exit 0  
else
echo "wrong"
exit 1
fi

exit 0
```

Comment: what's the question ?

Comment: Why do you need to use `seq`? `for ((i=$A; i<=$B; i++))` is more efficient and more idiomatic.

Comment: the question is _How can I get that?_ @alfasin

Comment: Thank you @chepner but I dont how I can use that, and I think if will appear like **2+3+4+5+6=20**

Comment: Don't edit "SOLVED" into your questions here. Selecting an answer with the checkbox marks it solved.

Comment: ok, sorry @CharlesDuffy and thenk you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This prints out that requested part (I think you already know how to add if/else).

```
read -p "Enter number 1: " a
read -p "Enter a number greater or equal than $a: " b

high=$(( b-1 ))
sum=0
str=""
for i in $(seq $a ${high}); do
 str="${str}${i}+"
 sum=$(( j+=i ))
done

sum=$(($sum+$b))
str="${str}${b}=${sum}"
echo $str
```

Comment: That was awesome dude, really thank you @arash
The world needs more people like you (all here)
appreciate.